# Split string,concatenate with another string and sort it

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, split

I am having two columns Col1 and Col2 in table Table1. If the 2 rows of Col1 has the values as  "C,B" & "A,B" and the 2 rows of Col2 has the values as "ASC" & "DES", I need the output in two rows in the order "ADES,B" & "CASC,B" (i.e; it should be sorted based on first value).

The Col1 value should be separated based on comma and it should be combined with the Col2 value and the outputs should be in sorted order based on first value.

I am having a string split function as follows:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString](@String nvarchar(4000), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items nvarchar(4000))       
as       
begin       
declare @idx int       
declare @slice nvarchar(4000)       

select @idx = 1       
    if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

while @idx!= 0       
begin       
    set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
    if @idx!=0       
        set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
    else       
        set @slice = @String       

    if(len(@slice)>0)  
        insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

    set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
    if len(@String) = 0 break       
end   
return       
end
```

**Input Column Sample Values:**

```
 Col1  Col2

  C,B  ASC

  A,B  DES
```

**Desired Ouptut:**

```
Output

ADES,B

CASC,B
```

Anybody please help out to get desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
   , LEFT(Co1,CHARINDEX(',',Co1)-1) 
      + Col2 
      + SUBSTRING(Co1,CHARINDEX(',',Co1),256) AS Result 
FROM Table1
ORDER BY Result
```

Replace 256 with length of your column or any larger value

**EDIT:**

Even better, using [`STUFF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function:

```
SELECT *, STUFF(Co1,CHARINDEX(',',Co1),0,Col2) AS Result 
FROM Table1
ORDER BY Result
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c2b9/2)**

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE TABLE Table1
        ([Col1] varchar(3), [Col2] varchar(3))
    ;

    INSERT INTO Table1
        ([Col1], [Col2])
    VALUES
        ('C,B', 'ASC'),
        ('A,B', 'DES')
    ;

**Query 1**:

    SELECT
          left(Col1,1) + col2 AS colA
        , right(col1,1)       AS colb
    FROM table1
    ORDER BY
          colA
        , colB




**[Results][2]**:

    | COLA | COLB |
    |------|------|
    | ADES |    B |
    | CASC |    B |



  [1]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9dbd/2
```